# Keras model gives huge negative values and model doesnt train at all

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So, I am trying to train a model to predict gomoku moves. I made a fake dataset to try to train and see what the model can learn.

The train(my train_x) variable loads a numpy array that contains the board states where my moves are -1 and opponent's moves are 1. The board is an 11 by 11 numpy array

[Array image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6vw.png)

For outputs of the model where for each board state a 1d of 121 elements array which gives the next move.

[Array Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G95KB.png)

On input of a training data I want the model to return a 121 element array of probability where the largest probability would be the predicted move.

But when I train the model [the model gets crazy negative loss values and it just doesnt train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Whe4.png)

I think I am doing some huge fundamental mistake. Can someone help me get the desired output.

This is link for the model and code I am trying to run

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hEmsSNKtQ06hvac9ZIPJh9H4tq2aXZeQ?usp=sharing

The model looks like this

```
model = Sequential([
  Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2,2), input_shape=(11, 11,1)),
  Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2,2)),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
  Dropout(.2),
  # Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2,2)),
  Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2,2)),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
  Dropout(.2),
  Flatten(),
  Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  Dense(121,activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using CNNs for such a problem. CNNs are used to extract and learn spatial features, instead, try representing the state of the board in the form of a vector or matrix. Then use Dense layers to learn the input-label mapping.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I know I just wanted to see what Cnn would do. I had the problem because of the negative values in my output labels which caused the loss to keep going negative. I fixed it and it fixed the problem :)